# Checking GWT project source, How we can devide client source and server source

Tags: gwt

Looking at Google GWT project source, How we can divide client source and server source. 
Do we need to any configurations such as these are client packages and these are server packages like wise.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html

I think it is a good idea to use the standard directory and package layout.